# navbar fixed using Bootstrap.js

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I am working on a webapp which uses Backbone + Bootstrap as the css framework.

I am not able to set the navbar fixed to the top using Bootstrap in mobile browsers.
As per Bootstrap all we need to do is add 'navbar-fixed-top' class in the navbar...but unfortunately its not working for me in mobile browsers but working in desktop browsers.

HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner" style="text-align:center">
    <div class="colL pull-left">
        <a href="/#back" id="back-btn" class="btns angular_btn pull-left" style="display:none"><span>Back</span></a>
        <a href="/#control_back" id="control-back-btn" class="btns angular_btn pull-left" style="display:none"><span>Back</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="colR pull-right">
        <a class="btns pull-right" id="home" style="display: none" href="/#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
        <a href="/#controls" id="controls" class="btns pull-right" data-toggle="tab">Now Playing</a>
    </div>
    <div class="colC">
        <div id="show_name"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm assuming you're using scrollspy?

Comment: and honestly i dont think anyone can help you if you dont provide any code.

Comment: nope...I am only using Bootstrap framework

Comment: well i dont see anything wrong. Maybe it's your css, you might have loaded your css after bootstrap, and overridden something? try removing everything except the navbar and see whether it sticks to the top.

Comment: yea I already tried that...by removing everything except the navbar...and it works fine. Also note that there is no inline css which could over-ride it.

Answer (score 0):

As of Bootstrap's v2.2.2 pushed in December 2012 fixed navbars do work on mobile using 'position: absolute'.

Answer (score -1):

Twitter Bootstrap does not support fixed navbars for mobile:

> Fixed on mobile isn't consistently possible, nor does it behave well—not even on iOS5. You're free to override that if you wish, but we won't be re-enabling until support is improved. (@markdotto commenting [this issue](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1617))

Comment: I tried removing everything except the navbar and it works fine in mobile.